# Trying to pass an object into $http request with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have an object, like this:

```
$scope.user = {name: "Jim", birthday: "1/1/90", address: "123 Easy St"}
```

I'm making an $http call to my server and I'd like to pass this user info. I'm trying like this:

```
$http({
    url: '/api/coolLookup/' + userID, 
    method: "GET",
    params: {user:$scope.user}
  }).success(function(data){
      // do stuff
  });
```

Within my server resource (I'm using `ExpressJS`/`Node` here) I'm trying to access the `user` object but cannot:

```
exports.coolLookup = function (req, res) {
    console.log("Here's the user")
    console.log(req.params.user)
}
```

`req.params.user` returns undefined in my console. Any idea what to do here?

Comment: Do you see the json object go out on the wire in the browser's network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Express you should do:

```
console.log(req.query.user);
```

(NOTE: `query`, not `params`)

This will give you a string, use `JSON.parse()` to convert it to an object.

Comment: Ah, beauty. `req.params.query` correctly returns the search params so it tripped me up.